# ¿Por qué me dice que mapa no esta declarado?

Tags: c++

Intento compilar y me salta un error al llamar a `mueve_coches(mapa)` y `mueve_guerreros(mapa)` donde me dice que mapa no ha sido declarado. `VVC` es un ***typdef*** de una matriz de un tipo en concreto y `scan` es una funcion que inicializa mapa. `Round` indica la ronda en la que estoy, que va de (**`0`**) a (**`499`**). No entiendo porque me surge este error.

```
virtual void play () {
  VVC mapa(64,vector<CellType>(64));
  if (round() == 0) scan(mapa);
  mueve_coches(mapa); //primero mover coches
  mueve_guerreros(mapa);
}
```

También dejo la función `scan` por si acaso y el **typedef** de VVC:

```
void scan(VVC& mapa) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 64; ++i) mapa[i][j] = cell(i,j).type;
    }
}
```

```
typedef vector<CellType> VC;
typedef vector<VC> VVC;
```

Y el error:

> AIVmorais.cc: In member function ‘virtual void Vmorais::play()’:
>   AIVmorais.cc:124:20: error: ‘mapa’ was not declared in this scope
>          mueve_coches(mapa); //primero mover coches

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: De casualidad tienes alguna funcion o metodo llamado `mapa`

Comment: No que yo sepa. Puedo cambiarle el nombre por si acaso pero me extrañaría mucho

Comment: ¿Ese es el único error que obtienes o tienes más errores?

Comment: La forma como tienes a `mapa` es como si fuera una funcion que recive dos parametros

Comment: Creo que has dado en el clavo @OrlandoDeLaRosa (eso se conoce como "*most vexing parse*") lo que me intriga es que no salga una alarma u otros errores por ello.

Comment: Es el único error que obtengo Paula_plus_plus. Entonces que forma sugieres para declarar esa matriz con un tamaño de 64x64 Orlando De La Rosa?

Comment: Creo que tiene errores en el loop interior.  Incrementa i y no j y no tiene {} .

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta y coloca como es que defines el typedef de VVC y te aseguro que @Paula_plus_plus podra ayudarte

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Sospercho que `VVC` es un **V**ector de **V**ectores de **C**ellType, es decir: `using VVC = std::vector<std::vector<CellType>`.

Comment: puesto, ya lo he añadido

Comment: Revisa tambien el comentario de @Duston, estas tbn incrementando `i` y no `j`

Comment: Si, eso lo he cambiado ahora. Un error muy grande por mi parte. Cuando llevas tantas horas mirando lineas de codigo dejas de ver estos lapsus, gracias por el apunte @Duston

Comment: Curiosamente, [a mi me funciona](https://wandbox.org/permlink/26GmuIJJTPFLK0qr) con GCC. ¿Qué compilador estás usando?

Comment: estoy usando g++ Concretamente: g++ -o nombre nombre.cc -std=c++11

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. He decidido no complicarme más y declararlo como variable global, dejar de pasarlo como parámetro y modificarlo directamente de la global. Buenas tardes ;)

Comment: @VíctorMorais te invito a que pases y leas en el centro de ayuda a como [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa gracias por la advertencia. Como se puede notar, soy nuevo en este sitio y aun me estoy acostumbrando a esta comunidad.

Comment: Aunque la ayuda que me habéis ido proporcionando a servido, seguían apareciendo nuevos errores así que he decidido declararlo como una variable global y dejar de pasar parámetros como referencia para modificarlo directamente.

Comment: Tranquilo que no es una advertencia, pero, de esta forma el contenido de la comunidad crece.